# ASPNET Core ActionResult property not serialize

Tags: asp.net-core, serialization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this object

```
[DataContract]
public class FilterList<T> : List<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult<FilterList<MyPOCO>> GetFilteredResult(string filter)
{
    var l = new FilterList<MyPOCO>();
    l.Total = 123456;
    // Continue to add many MyPOCO objects into the list
    return l;
}
```

I can get back the MyPOCO list at the client side, but the **l.Total** is NOT serialize. May I know what I had done wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround , you could try to use `[JsonObject]` attribute . But **the items will not be serialized**, because a JSON container can have properties, or items -- but not both. If you want both, you will need to add a synthetic list property to hold the items.

[JsonObject] will also cause base class properties such as `Capacity` to be serialized, which you likely do not want. To suppress base class properties, use [MemberSerialization.OptIn](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm). Thus your final class should look something like:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class FilterList<T> : List<T>
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    List<T> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                this.AddRange(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however if I were to have the list as a separate item, I do not need to derive from it at all.

Comment: Where do  you want to add total , the items or the each `MyPOCO` class ?